# Why doesn't this piece of code output anything

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Save below piece of code as `test.cpp` and then

```
$ g++ -O2 -o test test.cpp
```

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int x, int y) {
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    int ret = foo(x, y);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./test
```

Note:

1. G++ 8.2.0
2. Compile again without -O2 option then it prints `2`

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zbdW8vddq)

Comment: Your code exhibits **undefined behaviour** because the `foo` function is declared as returning an `int` but it doesn't actually return anything. Once UB is invoked, all explanations of actual behaviour are effectively meaningless.

Comment: That's why you need `-Werror`. Most of time warnings are getting ignored.

Comment: you asked your compiler to compile a function that returns an `int` without returning an `int`. No matter what the compiler does to your code it is equally wrong (or right).

Comment: `-Werror` and `-Wall` and ideally also `-O2` (which enables an extra warning)

Comment: That said, `gcc` can be rather over-enthusiastic about using undefined behaviour as an excuse to discard parts of the code that would be better retained

Comment: If you look at the generated code, it only initializes the I/O system, then it exits. This is how modern optimizers work; if the compiler knows that something definitely has undefined behaviour, it can assume that it never happens and discard it. Similarly, if something has undefined behaviour in certain conditions, it can assume that those conditions never hold.

Comment: It's what happens when compilers forget they're meant to be useful tools and instead focus on optimisation to the exclusion of all else

Comment: @JiříBaum The compiler is irreproachable in this case. It is acting exactly according to specifications. If there is UB, then that is the programmer's fault, and whatever the compiler ends up doing, it is free of any blame. It is correct for compilers to prioritize optimizations over trying to accommodate some expected or meaningful behavior UB. Doing otherwise is what would make it a less useful tool. It would be irrational to penalize correct code for the benefit of developers who accidentally or purposefully write broken code.

Comment: Technically correct but practically problematic. Other compilers define a null dereference (for instance) to be an error, which has been the convention for decades and results in much fewer surprises for the programmer

Comment: @JiříBaum That is precisely an example of penalizing correct code for the benefit of broken code. If there is a useful optimization opportunity that's related to excluding the possibility of a null pointer dereference, then it should ideally be taken. Working around this is what non-optimized debug builds are for. If you get unexpected behavior, you run a debug build and all those null pointer dereferences should now be left as they are and be easier to spot. Optimized release builds aught to take every advantage they can, they aren't meant to be easy to debug.

Comment: All code is broken

Comment: The purpose of a compiler is to be a useful tool, not a theoretical transform